# WPF MVVM: Isolating command logic from ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, prism

I'm giving my first steps with WPF and MVVM, using Prism. So far, so good, but there's a certain design approach I cannot seem to achieve.

In my UI, I have two ways of opening a file. There's a browse button that can be clicked and an Open File dialog will appear, prompt for the file, and open it. You can also drag and drop a file on top the UI, and it'll open it.

In order to isolate the Browse logic, I created a command for it. The first code smell appears, I need a result from it that is not exposed by the ICommand interface.

```cs
public class BrowseFileCommand: ICommand
{
    public string ExecutionResult { get; private set; }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter) => true;

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        var openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog()
        {
            Multiselect = false,
            Filter = "Event log files (*.evtx)|*.evtx"
        };

        ExecutionResult = openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true ? openFileDialog.FileName : null;
    }

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;
}
```

Then, in my ViewModel class, I can invoke it like this:

```cs
public class MainWindowViewModel: BindableBase
{
    public DelegateCommand BrowseFileCommand { get; set; }

    public MainWindowViewModel()
    {
        BrowseFileCommand = new DelegateCommand(BrowseAndOpenFile, () => _browseFileCommand.CanExecute(null));
        // ...
    }

    private BrowseFileCommand _browseFileCommand = new BrowseFileCommand();

    private void BrowseAndOpenFile()
    {
        _browseFileCommand.Execute(null);
        var fileName = _browseFileCommand.ExecutionResult;
        if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fileName))
            OpenFile(fileName);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Here are a few other code smells:

- I need to wrap up my command in another command that will read the value from it after executed
- I am not properly chaining up CanExecuteChanged events (I don't need to, but it seems I should if I am to nest commands)
- Calling CanExecute() with a null parameter (as far as I've seen, this is "common", but still a code smell to me), because `ICommand` requires it
- Calling CanExecute() without parameters, because Prism's `DelegateCommand` allows for it.
- I still left the "gluing" logic in the ViewModel, which is what I wanted to avoid in the first place.

**Is there a good way for me to completely isolate the logic to a Command / class?**

Note the following design restrictions:

- These actions *do* belong to the UI logic: the BrowseCommand is strictly tied to the UI technology being used
- Some of the commands may be shared between actions. Notice how OpenFile is the second step after browsing a file, but is the first step on Drop (not shown here).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ICommand` is primarily intended to be used only for binding to UI. It is not meant to be used for separation of behavior and called from within normal code. Which is why you are getting your code smell.

Instead, use normal language features(methods, inheritance, composition, etc..) to separate the concerns and just use `ICommand` commands to expose specific operations to the UI for binding.

Comment: Would this still apply to behaviors completely tied to UI, like my "BrowseFile"?

Comment: @Alpha No. If you want to separate some different concept then create your own abstraction.

Comment: If I understood correctly, then you would keep things like "BrowseFile" directly in the ViewModel, but as long as that becomes a little bit more complex, you'd isolate that complexity into a class of your own. That would become something you invoke from the VM. Similarly, for everything, managing the result and managing the invocation would still be left inside the VM, right?